# Show horizontal line separator between cell blocks in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using the `cell mode` plugin in `PyCharm` to separate new cells at `#%%`. How can I make the `PyCharm` editor to show a horizontal line between adjacent cell blocks akin Spyder?

```
 #%% first cell
 def foo():
     print("bar")
 ------------------ #this is what I want to see
 #%% second cell
 print("foo")
```

Comment: I would like to know the same thing.

Comment: search for "show method separator" in pycharm pressing shift button twice. That will lead you to this setting.